# Add link to another form's submission view

Tags: rsform

I have two separate forms - a user form and an incident form. In the user submission view, I need to generate a link to all incidents that the user may have. These users may have more than one incident and these incidents are all recorded as individual form submissions from the incident form.

I don't want to import data from one form to another, just provide a link to the incident submissions. It seems simple enough and I've be trying to figure this out but have not cracked it yet. I've been a user of RSform for a few years but have not come across anything this complicated yet (for me atleast) with my experience with it this component.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Much thanks!

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take the [tour]. Please provide us with the details of your failed attempts so that we don't recommend something that you've already tried.  Maybe you could mock up a screenshot image of what you want.  Maybe I am misunderstanding, but are you asking how to write query results (list of incident report ids to be converted to hyperlinks) into an RSForm form?

Comment: I'm asking for assistance with writing a query that locates the associated id's that link a user to an incident between the incident & user forms and I need to display a hyperlink of those incidents in the users submissions view section - see screenshot. Does that make more sense?  

I've never done a query like this before between two different RSforms. I've been going through their forums only to come up empty. Usually I can fumble my way through this but this request is a bit advanced for what I'm used to doing. 

[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/21oxfdpggo16mdz/sample.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: I guess I should be asking is what do I need to add to both forms that I can use to link these two forms together when queried to locate the submission view of the incident and display that as a link on the user's submission view page. Does that sound right?